# How to find the FrameLayout in my class

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout

I have an `XML` file where I have a `FrameLayout` and inside of it I have another `FrameLayout`.

I my class, I want to show the screen and hide the `FrameLayout` that is inside the other one, and when the user clicks in a button the `FrameLayout` was hidden appears, but I am getting an error.

Is that possible to find this `Framelayout`  inside the other one through  `findViewById`?

My code :

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor = "@color/white"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="70sp" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewwaves_startScreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/waves" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/teamInfoLayout"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMyTeams"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="My Teams:"
          />

           <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewClickOnTeamName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="(Click on a team name to race for that team)"
        />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Class:

```
ImageView waves;
View layout;
LayoutParams layoutParams, layoutParamsTextView;
FrameLayout layoutteamInfo;
private static float dx =0, dy=0, x= 0, y=0;


public ShowInfo(Context context) {
    super(context);
    waves = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewwaves_startScreen);
    layoutteamInfo = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    layoutteamInfo = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.teamInfoLayout);
}


public void hideImages()
{

    layoutteamInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    waves.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Waves are gone 

}
```

Update because of comments:

So, my logcats shows:

> 06-06 16:42:33.800: E/AndroidRuntime(2073): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-06 16:42:33.800:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2073):   at
>   com.qwantech.workshape.ShowInfo.hideImages(ShowInfo.java:33) 06-06
>   16:42:33.800: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at
>   com.qwantech.workshape.Start.onCreate(Start.java:47)

and I created another class "ShowInfo extends View" to deal with the images and Layout.

These codes are there.

In my class "Starts", I created an object:

```
ShowInfo showObj = new ShowInfo(getContext());
```

and in my `onCreate` of `Start` I call:

```
showObj.hideImages();
```

I am getting the error in the moment I calling this function.

Comment: what's the error? post your logcat

Comment: What layout are you inflating ? Post your code for setContentView(R.layout.yourXML);

Comment: post Start.java on create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working from another class, you need to pass the root element of your view to be able to use `findViewById()`. Otherwise, your class is out of context and cannot access the view element.

`mRootView.findViewById(R.id.teamInfoLayout)`  should work.

Comment: I find the solution: I could do everything in the same class I set the content view. I was getting the error just when I created another class to do it. I dont know why.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see why. I will update my answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is to inflate your XML layout file and find your frame using the layout.findViewById(...)

Example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfilename, null);
FrameLayout layoutteamInfo  = (FrameLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamInfoLayout);
```

This will get the second framelayout in your xml file

Comment: I did this, but I am still getting an error. The problem is the function hideImges/

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
waves = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewwaves_startScreen);
```

But there is no ImageView in your XML that has this id: imageViewwaves_startScreen. 
You have to create an ImageView inside Xml with that id

Try giving an id to your first FrameLayout.

If that doesnt work than try to copy this class that you have done for dealing with layout, to your Activity class, if this will work it means that raybaybay answer is the solution

Comment: Actually I had, I just forgot to put there. I update it. Thank you.